# heroku app error NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I receive the following error in the heroku build

> NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error remote:        NODE_ENV=production remote:
> NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false remote:
> remote: -----> Installing binaries remote:        engines.node
> (package.json):  unspecified remote:        engines.npm
> (package.json):   unspecified (use default) remote: remote:
> Resolving node version 12.x... remote:        Downloading and
> installing node 12.20.0... remote:        Using default npm version:
> 6.14.8 remote: remote: -----> Restoring cache remote:        - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached
> remote: remote: -----> Installing dependencies remote:        Prebuild
> detected (node_modules already exists) remote:        Rebuilding any
> native modules remote: remote:        > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall
> /tmp/build_914d999a/node_modules/core-js remote:        > node -e
> "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}" remote: remote: remote:
>
> > nodemon@2.0.6 postinstall /tmp/build_914d999a/node_modules/nodemon remote:        > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

my package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "galeria",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/index.js",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.8",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "serve": "^11.3.2"
  },
  "engine": {
    "node": "12.18.x",
    "npm": "6.14.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

my server, src/index.js:

```
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    
        require("dotenv").config();
    }
    const http = require('http');
    const express = require("express");
    const morgan = require("morgan");
    const multer = require("multer");
    const path = require("path");
    const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
    
    
    const app = express();
    const server = http.Server(app);
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });
    require("./database");
    
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/')))
    //Middlewares
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: path.join(__dirname, "public/uploads"),
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, new Date().getTime() + path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    
    })
    app.use(multer({ storage }).single('file'));
    
    const upload = multer({ storage });
    //Routes
    app.use(require("./routes"));
    
    
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server on port: " + port)
    })
```

any suggestions?

Comment: It is for setting the log level to show only errors, not an error.